# How to Implement MVW Pattern in existing asp.net web form application

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, webforms, asp.net-web-api2, mvw

I am working on asp.net web form application which is consist of aspx(html), code behind and JavaScript code. Now we want to upgrade our application into new technology using asp.net MVW (Model View Whatever) pattern but the base line is that the new pattern should be integrated in existing web form application so that the existing old web form should work as is and new screens will be implemented using MVW pattern, it will be consist of (Model, View, WebAPI & AngularJS)

My questing is it possible to implement MVW pattern in existing web form application! so that we can run two different approach (existing web form and MVW) under single web application.

I googled for such application sample but I found example only new webform application using the MVW pattern with no code behind of web form, I need the existing web form should work as is and new screen (pages) should be develop using new pattern.

Please help me if any one has link for such type of example.

Answer (score 0):

As the paradigm of model view whatever (MVW) adhere strongly to SPA and modular style programming with no postbacks of pages. If you read the documentation of angular which states that it works on MVW architecture I don't think that you can achieve it in web forms or it is not possible. Even if you take ASP.NET MVC it's hard to fit webforms with it.As Currently, we are going thru that transition phase.

You have to decouple the logic from tight bindings of web forms and make it modular by using web API and angular.

Hope It helps.